# How to skip an else statement a certain number of times, then start again

Tags: java, if-statement, skip

I have a list of names in an array, and there is some redundancy in it. I was able to get only unique names to print, but I need a way to print the first line, skip the printing however many times there was a redundancy, then continue printing the next name (all redundant instances were always next to eachother). Here is what I have for that part so far:

```
int x = 1;
int skipCount = 0;
while (x<i){
  if (titles[x].length() == titles[x-1].length()){
   //do nothing 
    skipCount++;
  }
  else{
    System.out.printf("%s\n", titles[x]);
  }
  x++;
}
```

So basically, how would I go about skipping the else statement 'skipCount' times, then have it start again? I haven't found much about this and am relatively new to java.

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. Could you give an example? titles + expected output?

Comment: You don't seem to have declared `i`?

Comment: @dra why are you comparing the titles by `length`?

Comment: Can you use a `Set`? That would remove duplicates for you upon insertion.

Comment: @ChrisW I think you can infer `i = titles.length`

Comment: You can't "skip" an `else` statement if the previous `if` evaluated to false. Perhaps you need to rework some of the logic? Just to clarify you are trying to simply stop from printing the same string twice?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Lets see if this makes sense: I have a bunch of html files that I took the <title> block out of. Many of these htmls have the same title, so I am trying to make a program to group them by title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use a [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html)? ;-)

```
final Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(titles));
for (final String title : set) {
  /* title is unique */
  System.out.println(title);
}
```

Some of the changes include using `println` rather than `printf("%s\n", ...)`, which is just clearer, and using an *enhanced `for` loop*, instead of manually tracking the position in the array in a loop.

To be honest, you might consider using a `Set<String>` in place of `String[]` for `titles` in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I couldn't get what you posted to work, but it definitely got me going in the right direction.